# Finding basis of a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the set of solutions to the system of linear equations

$x_1-2x_2+x_3=0,
2x_1-3x_2+x_3=0$
is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Find a basis for this subspace.

How do I approach this problem?

I know that dimension of $\mathbb R^3=3$ and so the dimension of the subspace is $3$ and the basis will contain $3$ vectors.

I have no clue how to find them using the given conditions. I do know that the $2$ equations in $3$ unknowns have infinitely many solutions. How do I take it from there?

Comment: You may want to start solving the system.  You would then need to find one or more vectors (that are linearly independent).  So that any solution can be written as a linear combination of the vectors you found.  You may see how to proceed once you've solved the system.

Comment: I used cross-multiplication to find a general solution in the form $(k,-k,k)$ but I don't know how to find a basis from here...

Comment: Actually $(k,-k,k)$ doesn't satisfy your equations.  But in principle, you could think of this set as $k(1,-1,1)$.  Do you see how this shows you what the basis would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific algorithm to follow if you want.

- First you row reduce the system.

$$ \left({\begin{matrix}
        1 & -2 & 1 \\
        2 & -3 & 1 \\
             \end{matrix}}\right)  \left({\begin{matrix}
        x_1  \\
        x_2  \\
        x_2  \\     \end{matrix}}\right)
 = 0 \iff \left({\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 &  - 1 \\
             \end{matrix}}\right)  \left({\begin{matrix}
        x_1  \\
        x_2  \\
        x_2  \\     \end{matrix}}\right)
 = 0 $$

- Then you rewrite the equations with the prominent variable on the left and all that is left on the right. Say there are $k$ rows in your system of $n$ variables. Then $k$ variables will have prominent columns while $n- k$ variables won't. So send these $n - k$ variables to other side of the equations. your set of solutions is obtained by taking any values whatsover for these $n - k$ variables. Now in our example,

$$ x_1 = x_3  $$

$$ x_2 = x_3  $$

Any values you wish to choose for $x_3$ will solve the system if you take the corresponding values for $x_1$ and $x_2$ which in our case is the same. So the set of solutions is of the form,

$$ \left({\begin{matrix}
        x_1  \\
        x_2  \\
        x_2  \\     \end{matrix}}\right) = \left({\begin{matrix}
        x_3  \\
        x_3  \\
        x_3  \\     \end{matrix}}\right) = x_3\left({\begin{matrix}
        1  \\
        1  \\
        1  \\     \end{matrix}}\right)$$

where $x_3$ is any scalar in $\Bbb R$. Your basis is staring at you.

Comment: So the subspace has dimension 1 in this case?

Comment: @Diya: That's right. For more info, Read *Linear Algebra by Hoffman, Kunze*. Method is rigorously presented there.

Comment: Thank you. What if I'm given one equation though? Say $a_1-a_3-a_4=0$? I'm finding sums like that, so...

Comment: Same story. $ a_1 = a_3 + a_4 $. So all your solutions are of the form $ \left({\begin{matrix}
        a_3 + a_4  \\
        a_2  \\
        a_3  \\
        a_4 \\
        \end{matrix}}\right) = a_2 \left({\begin{matrix}
        0  \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{matrix}}\right) + a_3 \left({\begin{matrix}
          1  \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{matrix}}\right) + a_4 \left({\begin{matrix}
          1  \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{matrix}}\right)  $ where $ a_2, a_3, a_4 $ are arbitrary scalars.